# How to fix "Error: arguments imply differing number of rows"?

Tags: r, json, api

I'm trying to get an API response using a URL that exists in an API data frame I just got, but I'm receiving the error:

*"Error: arguments imply differing number of rows"*

Does someone now how to fix it?

#### SCRIPT SO FAR

```
install.packages("jsonlite", "httr")
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

### Generating URL and first request

url_deputados <- "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados?idLegislatura=57&ordem=ASC&ordenarPor=nome"
get_deputados <- GET(url_deputados)

### Transforming it to text

deputados_text <- content(get_deputados, "text")
deputados_text

### Converting

deputados_json <- fromJSON(deputados_text, flatten = TRUE) 
deputados_json

### Transforming it to table

deputados_df <- as.data.frame(deputados_json) 
deputados_df

### And removing the two last columns which I don't need

deputados_df <- deputados_df[1:9]

### Now for the secondary requisitions, I'm creating a URL with the Id that is present in the first column of the data frame I just got

url_base <- "``https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/``"
url_deputados <- "deputados/"
url_id <- deputados_df$dados.id
id_list <- c(url_id)
i <- 1

url <- paste0(url_base, url_deputados, id_list[i])
url

### Up to this point everything works, but I need to make sequential requests so I can GET the info for the next line of the existing data frame

while (i <= 531) {
    print("Próxima página encontrada, baixando...")   
    get_deputados_id <- GET(paste0(url_base, url_deputados, id_list[i]))
    deputados_id_text <- content(get_deputados_id, "text")
    deputados_id_json <- fromJSON(deputados_id_text, flatten = TRUE)   
    deputados_id_df <- as.data.frame(deputados_id_json)
    i <- i + 1
}
```

And this is where I receive the message error

Comment: Is there a reason you have double-backticks in your `url_base`? I'd expect `"https://..."`, but you have `"\`\`https://...\`\`"`, which is certainly going to disrupt things.

Answer (score 1):

When you run into problems at one line in your code, ***stop*** and look at the previous results. For instance, for me (since you didn't specify), I'm getting an error here:

```r
deputados_df <- as.data.frame(deputados_json) 
# Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
#   arguments imply differing number of rows: 532, 3
```

So ... let's look at `deputados_json`:

```r
str(deputados_json)
# List of 2
#  $ dados:'data.frame':    532 obs. of  9 variables:
#   ..$ id           : int [1:532] 220593 204379 220714 221328 204560 204528 121948 74646 160508 136811 ...
#   ..$ uri          : chr [1:532] "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/220593" "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/204379" "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/220714" "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/221328" ...
#   ..$ nome         : chr [1:532] "Abilio Brunini" "AcÃ¡cio Favacho" "Adail Filho" "Adilson Barroso" ...
#   ..$ siglaPartido : chr [1:532] "PL" "MDB" "REPUBLICANOS" "PL" ...
#   ..$ uriPartido   : chr [1:532] "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/37906" "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/36899" "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/37908" "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/37906" ...
#   ..$ siglaUf      : chr [1:532] "MT" "AP" "AM" "SP" ...
#   ..$ idLegislatura: int [1:532] 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 ...
#   ..$ urlFoto      : chr [1:532] "https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/220593.jpg" "https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/204379.jpg" "https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/220714.jpg" "https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/221328.jpg" ...
#   ..$ email        : chr [1:532] "dep.abiliobrunini@camara.leg.br" "dep.acaciofavacho@camara.leg.br" "dep.adailfilho@camara.leg.br" "dep.adilsonbarroso@camara.leg.br" ...
#  $ links:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ rel : chr [1:3] "self" "first" "last"
#   ..$ href: chr [1:3] "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados?idLegislatura=57&ordem=ASC&ordenarPor=nome" "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados?idLegislatura=57&ordem=ASC&ordenarPor=nome&pagina=1&itens=1000" "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados?idLegislatura=57&ordem=ASC&ordenarPor=nome&pagina=1&itens=1000"
```

(Hint: that's not unambiguously converted into a frame.)

My guess is that you just need to access `$dados`:

```r
head(deputados_json$dados)
#       id                                                        uri            nome siglaPartido                                               uriPartido siglaUf idLegislatura                                                       urlFoto                            email
# 1 220593 https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/220593  Abilio Brunini           PL https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/37906      MT            57 https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/220593.jpg  dep.abiliobrunini@camara.leg.br
# 2 204379 https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/204379  AcÃ¡cio Favacho          MDB https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/36899      AP            57 https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/204379.jpg  dep.acaciofavacho@camara.leg.br
# 3 220714 https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/220714     Adail Filho REPUBLICANOS https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/37908      AM            57 https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/220714.jpg     dep.adailfilho@camara.leg.br
# 4 221328 https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/221328 Adilson Barroso           PL https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/37906      SP            57 https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/221328.jpg dep.adilsonbarroso@camara.leg.br
# 5 204560 https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/204560    Adolfo Viana         PSDB https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/36835      BA            57 https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/204560.jpg    dep.adolfoviana@camara.leg.br
# 6 204528 https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/204528 Adriana Ventura         NOVO https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/37901      SP            57 https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/204528.jpg dep.adrianaventura@camara.leg.br
```

After that, make sure you fix your `url_base`, It should almost certainly not contain so many backticks.

Finally, you should do the same thing in your `while` loop:

```r
while (i <= 531) {
    get_deputados_id <- GET(paste0(url_base, url_deputados, id_list[i]))
    deputados_id_text <- content(get_deputados_id, "text")
    deputados_id_json <- fromJSON(deputados_id_text, flatten = TRUE)   
    # deputados_id_df <- as.data.frame(deputados_id_json)
    deputados_id_df <- deputados_id_json$dados
    i <- i + 1
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the answer!
I'm trying working around the issue and what I noticed is that when running the loop the last page of it doesn't necessarily have 100 itens, as all of the others. Do you now a way around that? I couldn't create a loop until having no result.

BTW: the backticks were just an issue with transposing to Stack overflow, they're no in the original code.

Comment: I know nothing about the data on the API. It seems likely to me that they just don't have enough data for the last page, perhaps you've exhausted what they have? (It would be more surprising to me if the data available is always on a multiple of 100 rows.)